# Validation of checkboxes in custom forms does not work

Tags: magento-2.2.5

Check this below code. I have added one checkbox on newsletter footer subscribe.phtml. If we are custom add checkbox on this then form submit without form fill up.
Site Link : http://kkmag2.dev-site.me/

```
<form class="form subscribe"
          novalidate
          action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
          echo $block->getFormActionUrl() ?>"
          method="post"
          data-mage-init='{"validation": {"errorClass": "mage-error"}}'
          id="newsletter-validate-detail">
        <div class="field newsletter">
                <input name="email" type="email" id="newsletter" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo __('Email address') ?>" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
        </div>

        <div class="field input-box custom-required-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" title="<?php echo __('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?>" value="1" id="is_subscribed_footer" class="form-control checkbox required-entry" style="width: auto;" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            <label for="is_subscribed_footer"><?php echo __("Yes, I would like to sign up to find out about Kilkenny's Exclusive Offers**") ?></label>
        </div>

        <div class="actions">
            <button class="btn-novetty action subscribe "
                     type="submit">
             <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                    echo __('Sign Up') ?>
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Have you get any error in console?

Comment: I have added name="dummy" and this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" title="<?php echo __('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?>" name="dummy" value="" id="is_subscribed_footer" class="form-control checkbox required-entry" style="width: auto;" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
```

name field missing, name field is compulsory for validation.

Comment: Nice! it Works.